# ARCore - parameter to check if VPS is tracking

Tags: geospatial, arcore

When I use the sample project provided, I can get the horizontal accuracy up to < 0.5m when I am next to the street view road. And I think the VPS is tracked such that the accuracy get accurate.
But when I get away from the main road and get into a car non-accessible area, even there is street view in Google Maps, the accuracy value get larger and larger, and may up to 10-20m, which I think the VPS is not tracked.

I want to ensure my understanding is correct, and have more understanding of which place/area can get tracked by geospatial API with high accuracy. Do ARCore Geospatial API provide any variables that shown the status of VPS checking? I have gone through the documentation but cannot find one that is related

Gone through below pages:
https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/unity-arf/class/Google/XR/ARCoreExtensions/AREarthManager